# if Hashmap uses linkedlist internally why does it need to increase capacity

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, bucket

if Hashmap uses linkedlist internally why does it need to increase capacity .also if we are increasing buckets all the time then many buckets will remain empty with load factor as 0.75?

Comment: Say you have 10 buckets, 1_000_000 elements, and a perfect distribution, how many elements will each bucket (linked list) contain? What kind of worst case performance will you expect for a look up? What if you had 100_000 buckets?

Comment: linkedlists are one way to deal with collisions. In the linked case when you have a collision you simply store both objects in the same location, and when looking up you have to check which one to return, while open addressing when it finds a slot already full computes a different hash for the same object to find an empty slot, this means that you have more full slots and lookup could require computing various hashes. If you have 1 million collision, without resizing the hashmap you end up with a 1 million linked list (open addressing simply fails at a certain point when the table is full)

Answer (score 0):

HashMap does not use LinedList always, it uses array. For e.g. if a create a new hashmap object then array of size 16 is created. Each index contains 4 parts containing key,value,hashcode,next.

LinedList is formed in index when collision(same hashcode) happens and this concept is called separate chaining.
For e.g. if you put 2 objects in map object having the same hashcode then separate chaining will happen otherwise 2 buckets will be created.

Comment: When multiple objects fall into the same bucket then searching time gets increased making it worst case scenario of O(n).